# How do you add content to a tab control dynamically in wcf?

Tags: wpf, wcf, tabcontrol

How do you add content to a tab control dynamically in wcf?  I mean add content to the display area that comes visibile when clicking on the tab control.

Allow me to rephrase this.  I have a WCF app.  In this app, I have a tab control that id defined in the XAML.  It is easy to add content to the pages of the tab control in the XAML.  How do I add content to the pages in the C# code at tuntime?

Comment: I think you're confusing "WCF" and "WPF". WCF is "Windows Communication Foundation", and has nothing to do with user interface controls.

Comment: You should explain your question alittle better if you'd like to get answer. Do you wan't a dynamic number of TabItems based on the data?

You can look up {DynamicResource} and other binding commands to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean WPF:

```
((TabItem)tabControl1.Items[0]).Content = new Button() { Content = "Dynamically Added Button" };
```

This adds a button to the first tab page. You could replace the button in this example with any other content.